# What's the best way to use a gist index on tsrange to check if a time occurs after the range?

Tags: postgresql, index, range-types, gin-index

## table (simplified)

```
                                        Table "public.events"
      Column      |            Type             |                       Modifiers                        
------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------
 id               | integer                     | not null default nextval('events_id_seq'::regclass)
 duration         | integer                     | not null
 start_at         | timestamp without time zone | 
Indexes:
    "events_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "my_idx" gist (tsrange(start_at, end_at(events.*), '[)'::text))
```

## function

```
CREATE FUNCTION end_at(rec events)
  RETURNS timestamp without time zone
  IMMUTABLE
  LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
  SELECT $1.start_at + ($1.duration * ('00:00:01'::interval));
$$;
```

## what I am already doing successfully

The index is used for queries like this:

```
-- check if current time is within the start and end times
-- of event
where localtimestamp <@ tsrange(start_at, events.end_at, '[)')
```

And it works well.

## what I want to do

I want to query for events where the current time is after they have ended. Ways I know of how to do this:

- `where tsrange(localtimestamp, localtimestamp, '[]') >> tsrange(start_at, events.end_at, '[)')`. I'm pretty sure this is the semantics I want, and `explain analyze` says it's using the index, but it's a bit ugly and I'm wondering if there's a better way to express this (and also am vaguely uncertain it's the semantics I want, as I am new to ranges).
- `where localtimestamp > upper(tsrange(start_at, events.end_at, '[)'))` + a btree index on `upper(tsrange(start_at, events.end_at, '[)'))`. This will work well, but requires keeping another index around.
- `where localtimestamp > events.end_at`. + a btree index on `events.end_at`. Same situation as above.

Is there a more elegant (or correct) way to achieve the first bullet point above?

Any other ideas for how to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres doesn't support any operators for this. As pointed out by @evan-carroll, it probably could and should.

So, the best solution is

```
where tsrange(localtimestamp, localtimestamp, '[]') >> tsrange(start_at, events.end_at, '[)')
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to query for events where the current time is after they have ended. Ways I know of how to do this:

You can see the [GiST operators here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/gist-builtin-opclasses.html). You can see the list in `range_ops`,

```
&& &> &< >> << <@ -|- = @> @>
```

As you indicated the one you probably want is `<<`, `>>`. I would use `<<`.

Is it ugly? Yes. The range type is great if you're working with ranges on both sides, here you're not. You're not even storing the range type on the table. I would recommend you do that.

I'm not sure this index condition even works,

```
"my_idx" gist (tsrange(start_at, end_at(events.*), '[)'::text))
```

Have you tested that? I mean, PostgreSQL can verify the `start_at` works, my assumption is that it's not smart enough to work with `end_at` with `events.*` (what if one of the values (columns) used in the `end_at` is changed from table creation to call? Even if never happens, how would PostgreSQL know that). I would store the `tsrange` on the table and drop all those associated columns.

**Ignore the below, looking into it.**

<s>Also you can consider making it shorter by not constructing the rhs range.</s>

```
SELECT tsrange('yesterday', 'tomorrow') @> timestamp without time zone 'now';
SELECT tsrange('yesterday', 'tomorrow') @> 'now'::timestamp without time zone;
```

Or the like if you prefer that format. Or the following, which seems like an anti-pattern.

```
SELECT tsrange('yesterday', 'tomorrow') @> '[now,now]';
```

Or you can use `tstzrange` (which is probably an all around better idea),

```
SELECT tstzrange('yesterday', 'tomorrow') @> now();
```

Comment: Ahh, I see they don't define those `>>` or `<<` for `tstzrange >> timestamp with time zone` That's likely a bug.

Comment: i'm talking about your examples with `@>` -- that operator tests for inclusion. if it returns false, we don't know if the tested element comes before or after the range. my queries need to know this.

Comment: Right, I'm telling you that you *should* be able to replace it with `<<` or `>>` that you can't makes me think it is a bug. I just wrote you pseduocode to show that `range oppr item` should work on GiST but it doesn't work for all the operators, and I think that's unintended.